# For tab panel iconCls is not working on Android

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have created tab panel and I have used iconCls property to show different icons on tab buttons. This works fine on chrome browser on desktop and on safari on iPad. But these icon images are not displaying on andorid tab, instead it displays blank square.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the element in chrome and also look at the console log. If you are debugging, then it may work in the web browser but will tell you what error has occurred.

Otherwise, make sure your stylesheet is linked correctly in android and try using the default iconCls classes to see if those work. If you are creating a custom one and not using sass, then you probably are not linking the actual icon file correctly.

Otherwise, provide the code for the tab buttons your custom css if you are using any.